# Data from Android App -> MYSQL

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an android application which is to collect data and then send it to a web directory.

So lets say a want to collect an array of data on the phone, and then after clicking a button send it all to the online directory as a file or stream. It does not even need to get a response - although in the future a confirmation would be handy.

how to be send to data to mysql

i submit my code as follow

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    InputStream inputStream;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lat","19.80"));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lon","13.22"));

                 try{

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/guestfeedback/connection.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());


                 }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
        }
```

Comment: i am trying to send 3 different value to mysql from android.

Comment: I know what you want to do. I asked [what you tried yet](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) to accomplish this. :)

Comment: @alextsc that post is awesome

Comment: Not mine, floats around here. Thanks for posting that code Piyush. =)

Comment: but the in server databse the both value not be inserted.why?

Comment: Debugging 101: Isolate the problem. Are you getting the request on the server side? Insert some logging there, check the POST variables, make sure this is even an Android problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html), personally. The documentation on both of them is pretty easy to follow.

Comment: Very good way of handling this. I would personally like to use an AsyncTask out of preference, but IntentService seems very handy for someone who does not have threading experience.

Comment: IntentService was created to cover the basic AsyncTask setup, if I recall correctly. In any event, the user didn't give the impression that asking them to handle the more complex AsyncTask would be worth the benefits it yields.

Comment: No definitely. I'm saying that this method is very elegant. After reading the documentation, it actually seems like IntentService basically does what AsyncTask should do anyhow, but with less involvement and without the option of being able to handle the data that doInBackground would pass to other AsyncTask methods. This seems like the best solution to the OPs question.